# How to disable textarea after all the rows have been added

Tags: jquery

I have a table where the user can add rows to it but each row is numbered. Now the user enters a number in a textbox for the number of rows he/she wants to add before they actually start adding rows. Below is the code where if the number of rows that has been added is over the number entered by the user, then it stops adding the rows.

```
if (qnum > <?php echo (int)@$_POST['textQuestion']; ?>) { 
    return; 
}
```

Example: if user entered in the number 5 in a textbox, then the user can only add 5 rows, if the user tries to add another row, then no row is added because user can't add more than 5 rows.

Now the above works fine. But then what I want to do is that when the number of rows added has met its limit, then I want it to disable the textarea on top so i changed the code to this below:

```
   if (qnum > <?php echo (int)@$_POST['textQuestion']; ?>) { 
      $('#questionTextArea').attr('disabled', 'disabled'); 
    return; 
}
```

The problem is that if I do the code above then it disables the textarea straight away which is incorrect. What should happen is that it should allow the user to add the maximum table rows it is allowed to add and when the user reaches that limt, then disable the textarea. Does anyone know how to achieve this?

Below is the function where it adds table rows:

```
function insertQuestion(form) {   

            if (qnum > <?php echo (int)@$_POST['textQuestion']; ?>) {
            $('#questionTextArea').attr('disabled', 'disabled'); 
    return;
}

    var $tbody = $('#qandatbl > tbody'); 
    var $tr = $("<tr class='optionAndAnswer' align='center'></tr>");
    var $qid = $("<td class='qid'>" + qnum + "</td>");




    $tr.append($qid);   
    $tbody.append($tr); 

    $(form).find('.numberOfQuestions').val(qnum);

    ++qnum;


}
```

Below is the textarea I want to disable:

```
<table id="question">
<tr>
    <td rowspan="3">Question:</td> 
    <td rowspan="3">
        <textarea id="questionTextArea" rows="5" cols="40" name="questionText"></textarea>
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a bunch of code listed which is good, but it doesn't seem to fit together well.

When does insertQuestion() get called? What triggers this?

This line `$(form).find('.numberOfQuestions').val(qnum);` references a class numberOfQuestions but I don't see that class used anywhere?

This row: `var $tbody = $('#qandatbl > tbody');` references an object with ID qandatbl however I don't see this defined anywhere.

Please provide a complete code sample and I will try to help you.

Comment: This isn't an answer, it's a comment.

Comment: Sorry I'm new here, didn't know how to comment

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this using the .keyup() event handler in jQuery.

The following function disables the element if it contains more than the allowed number of line breaks.

```
function limitRows() {
  var $this = $(this);
  var allowedRows = parseInt($this.attr("rows"));
  $this.prop("disabled", $this.val().split("\n").length > allowedRows);
}

$("#questionTextArea").keyup(limitRows);
```

You can then populate the `rows` attribute with PHP like so.

```
<textarea id="questionTextArea" 
  rows="<?php echo (int)@$_POST['textQuestion']; ?>" 
  cols="40" name="questionText"></textarea>
```

See working example here: http://jsfiddle.net/e4SNa/

**STRONG WORD OF CAUTION....**

I would advise against this approach because if the user is typing in their final line and accidentally presses "enter", then they field becomes disabled and they don't have the opportunity to fix their mistake.